# how can i pass xml format data from flex to python

Tags: python, mysql, flex3

i want to pass xml format data into python from flex.i know how to pass from flex but my question is how can i get the passed data in python and then the data should be inserted into mysql.and aslo i want to retrieve the mysql data to the python(cgi),the python should convert all the data into xml format,and pass all the data to the flex..
Thank's in advance.....

Comment: Are you asking how to write a web service in Python that accepts Flex messages?

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208528 for more details, here is a breif overview of what I think you are looking for.

The SimpleXMLRPCServer library allows you to easily create a server. Here's about the simplest server you can create, which provides two services to manipulate strings:

```
import sys
from random import shuffle
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

class MyFuncs:
    def reverse(self, str) :
        x = list(str);
        x.reverse();
        return ''.join(x);
    def scramble(self, str):
        x = list(str);
        shuffle(x);
        return ''.join(x);

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))
server.register_instance(MyFuncs())
server.serve_forever()
```

Once you make a connection to the server, that server acts like a local object. You call the server's methods just like they're ordinary methods of that object.

This is about as clean an RPC implementation as you can hope for (and other Python RPC libraries exist; for example, CORBA clients). But it's all text based; not very satisfying when trying to create polished applications with nice GUIs. What we'd like is the best of all worlds -- Python (or your favorite language) doing the heavy lifting under the covers, and Flex creating the user experience.

To use the library, download it and unpack it somewhere. The package includes all the source code and the compiled as3-rpclib.swc library -- the .swc extension indicates an archive file, and pieces of this library can be pulled out and incorporated into your final .swf. To include the library in your project, you must tell Flexbuilder (you can get a free trial or just use the free command-line tools, and add on the Apollo portion) where the library is located by going to Project|Properties and selecting "Apollo Build Path," then choosing the "Library path" tab and pressing the "Add SWC..." button. Next, you add the namespace ak33m to your project as seen in the code below, and you're ready to create an XMLRPCObject.

Note: the only reason I used Apollo here was that I was thinking in terms of desktop applications with nice UIs. You can just as easily make it a Flex app.

Here's the entire Apollo application as a single MXML file, which I'll explain in detail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:ApolloApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    xmlns:ak33m="http://ak33m.com/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Form>
        <mx:FormHeading label="String Modifier"/>
        <mx:FormItem label="Input String">
            <mx:TextInput id="instring" change="manipulate()"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem label="Reversed">
            <mx:Text id="reversed"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem label="Scrambled">
            <mx:Text id="scrambled"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
    <ak33m:XMLRPCObject id="server" endpoint="http://localhost:8000"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.collections.ItemResponder;
            private function manipulate() : void {
                server.reverse(instring.text).addResponder(new ItemResponder(reverseResult, onFault));
                server.scramble(instring.text).addResponder(new ItemResponder(scrambleResult, onFault));
            }
            private function reverseResult(event : ResultEvent, token : AsyncToken = null) : void {
                reversed.text = event.result.toString();
            }
            private function scrambleResult(event : ResultEvent, token : AsyncToken = null) : void {
                scrambled.text = event.result.toString();
            }
            private function onFault (event : FaultEvent, token : AsyncToken = null) : void {
                Alert.show(event.fault.faultString, event.fault.faultCode);
            }           
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:ApolloApplication>
```